# Drupal xml-rpc issue

Tags: java, web-services, drupal, xml-rpc, drupal-services

I developed an application in **java**, and I want to connect my application to my drupal site, I use the services module and drupal xmlrpc for web service.

I tested on my local machine localhost and it works without problems, but when I try on the website of my company I get the following error:

```
Failed to parse server's response: Expected methodResponse element, got front
```

I tried sniffing the packets and I saw that the packet has been sent by the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I used burp suite to see the packets sent, I found the problem it is the XML response:

```
<front><?xml version="1.0"?>

<methodResponse>
  <params>
  <param>
    <value><struct>
  <member><name>sessid</name><value><string>RnpLboQS6d-4AAak-
```

Here there is a `<front>` tag that is added to the xml, when I remove this tag with burp it works perfectly, thats why we have : 
Failed to parse server's response: Expected methodResponse element, **got front**
but how to solve this problem with drupal?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: but maybe it will help him a little

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we could use a java proxy to get the response from the server and try to modify it to delete the front tag from the xml ?